# What difference between argv[1]+1 and argv[2]

Tags: c++

I know this question is basic, I also newbie, so plz help me clear this problem:

I have this code:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    if (*argv[1] == L'-' && (!_wcsicmp(L"install", argv[1]+1)))
    {
        wprintf(L"You pressed: -install !");
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Unknown");
    }
}
```

It work OK, but if I replace to:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    if (*argv[1] == L'-' && (!_wcsicmp(L"install", argv[2])))
    {
        wprintf(L"You pressed: -install !");
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Unknown");
    }
}
```

It's break when run.

I don't know

- Why use argv[1]+1
- What difference between argv[1]+1 and argv[2] (I've used above).

Anyone explain for me, and give me document about wchar_t ???

Comment: In any half-decent language, the difference would be 'type mismatch'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First,**
*Why use argv[1]+1:*
--> _wcsicmp require POINTER, so you need pass: argv[1] + 1 or argv[2]

**Second,**
*What difference between argv[1]+1 and argv[2] (I've used above). :*
--> 
Do you see second argument of wmain: wchar_t *argv[] ? - This is mean POINTER to ARRAY (same same POINTER to POINTER).

Each argument separate by space.
So, argv[1] is pointer point to second argument, argv[2] is pointer point to third argument.
And, argv[1]+1 increase address in pointer by 1 (mean, that pointer will point to second character in second argument string)

Answer (score 2):

argv[1]+1 points to the second character in the argv[1] string, while argv[2] points to the next string.

Comment: ...I'm sorry to use similar words as in your answer, however I didn't find that until my answer is posted and then your answer is loaded ><

Comment: also I suppose you want to say "while argv[2] points to the `third` string."

Answer (score 1):

`argv[1] + 1` is a pointer to the second character in `argv[1]` while `argv[2]` is the third element (pointer to character) in `argv`.

```
argv[1] == *(argv + 1)
argv[2] == *(argv + 2)
argv[1] + 1 == *(argv + 1) + 1 != argv[2]
```